# How to change the output color without using echo?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to change the output color without using echo?
Something like "set color to yellow".

I have a script

```
#!/bin/bash
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

echo -e ${YELLOW}
cat file.txt | awk 'NR==1 { print $0; }'
echo -e ${BLUE}
cat file.txt | awk 'NR==2 { print $0; }'
echo -e ${NC}
```

which prints the first line of file.txt in yellow and the second line in blue. But it also adds extra lines in the places where I have "echo" commands.

I tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

${YELLOW} cat file.txt | awk 'NR==1 { print $0; }'
${BLUE} cat file.txt | awk 'NR==2 { print $0; }' ${NC}
```

But it doesn't work because "echo" command needs -e parameter to display colors.

So my question is: Can I change the output color without using echo? If not, how to remove these extra lines between lines of the file? Is it possible to correct this script to not generate extra lines?

Current output:

```
 
first line of file.txt

second line of file.txt
```

Desirable output:

```
first line of file.txt
second line of file.txt
```

Comment: You can try `prinft` instead of `echo -e`

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf`.

```
 printf '\e[1;34m%-6s\e[m' "First line of text in BLUE"
 printf '\e[1;31m%-6s\n\e[m' "Second line of text in RED WITH A NEW LINE"
```

Here is a tiny `bash` function to do this:

```
$ cat col.sh
#!/bin/bash

colprint()
{
    printf '\e[1;%dm%-6s\n\e[m' "$1" "$2"
}

# For your input file.
colprint 31 "$(awk 'NR==1{print;}' file.txt)"
colprint 34 "$(awk 'NR==2{print;}' file.txt)"
colprint 33 "$(awk 'NR==3{print;}' file.txt)"
```

Output in colors of course on a `xterm` with colors.

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo -e -n "$YELLOW"
```

---

`-n`: not add extra newline

Comment: OP's question asked specifically not to use `echo`.

Comment: It's OK, it also solves the problem with newlines :). I didn't think about modifying the echo command.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tput`:

```
#!/bin/bash

yellow() { tput setaf 3; }
blue() { tput setaf 4; }
nc() { tput sgr0; }

[[ -t 1 ]] || export TERM=dumb

yellow
cat file.txt | awk 'NR==1 { print $0; }'
blue
cat file.txt | awk 'NR==2 { print $0; }'
nc
```

That way you don't have to hard code terminal codes, and the terminal type and capabilities will be respected. For example, if you're using a terminal that doesn't support colors, you'll get uncolored text instead of garbage.

Here, that same feature is used to get uncolored text when `stdout` is not a terminal, which is the canonical Unix behavior to avoid problems when piping to other programs.

Comment: Sadly, it is becoming less the canonical behavior.  I seem to increasingly encounter tools that write terminal color codes to regular files and pipes.

Comment: TBH, these days I'm pleasantly surprised when a non-native program just manages to set a useful exit code.